# Use complete content of node as test expression

Tags: xslt, expression

i have a xml with some structure like this:

```
<data>
  <cond>5 &lt; 10</cond>
</data>
```

Is it possible to have something evaluated by xsl like this?:

```
<xsl:when test="data/cond">
  <!-- do something if 5 is smaller than 10 -->
</xsl:when>
```

Regards
Kai

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There some processors providing an extension function, for instance Saxon with http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/extensions/functions/evaluate.xml respectively http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/extensions/functions/evaluate-node.xml which you can use as e.g. `<xsl:when test="saxon:evaluate-node(data/cond)">...</xsl:when>`. But neither XSLT 1.0 or 2.0 have such a feature built in.

Comment: Yes, that would be it. It's available in the commercial version of Saxon, sadly not in the free Saxon HE. Thank you for that information.